# How can we calculate time spent on each server by my request when the request have to go on multiple node?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, server-monitoring

I am testing a software service which is on the distributed architecture. In my system there are 5 nodes.

- Client Node
- Front End Node
- Back End Node
- Database Node
- External Node

The request travels as follows 
Client Node -> Front End Node -> Back End Node -> Database Node -> Back End Node -> Front End Node -> Both(External Node/Client Node)

I need to calculate the time spent by request on each node and network delay on each node.

Please suggest some open source tool which can help me to find the solution.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter does not allow you to do that.

I am not aware of Open Source tools that would let you do that.

You could have a look at APM like AppDynamics, New Relic or Dynatrace for commercial tools.

You could build this with open source frameworks and custom development:

- You would use a UUID accross your call
- Make each stack report timing and adding this UUID in reported information in a Time Series DB like InfluxDB
- Use tool like Grafana for reporting

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.